# Delphi Access Violation calling a C++ DLL that implements an interface

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, access-violation

To import a DLL in Delphi I've written a unit translating a .h file
This DLL allow me to define a procedure to monitor two values and use them in my app.

the original .h file is:

```
class MyINTERFACE
{
   public:
   virtual void MonitorProc(int value1, int value2) = 0;
};

extern MY_API MyHANDLE* Init();
extern MY_API UINT InitMonitorProc(MyHANDLE * handle, MyINTERFACE * pMyProc);
```

and this is my translation:

```
unit myCdllUnit;

interface

const

 TMyHANDLE = DWORD;  

 MyINTERFACE = class
 public
   procedure MonitorProc(value1: longint;  value2: longint); virtual; cdecl; abstract;
 end;

function Init(): TMyHANDLE; cdecl; external 'myCdll.dll'; 
function InitMonitorProc(handle: TMyHANDLE; pMyProc: MyINTERFACE):DWORD; cdecl; external 'myCdll.dll';

implementation

end.
```

in my main form I override the MonitorProc (initially only with "inherited" to test the calling)

```
TMyMonitor = class(MyINTERFACE)
public
procedure MonitorProc(value1: longint; value2: longint); override;
end;

procedure TMyMonitor.MonitorProc(value1: longint;  value2: longint);
begin
  inherited;
end;   <--------------------------- here get an Access Violation
```

and in my FormCreate I pass an istance to InitMonitorProc

```
MyMonitor := TMyMonitor.Create;
InitMonitorProc(Handle, MyMonitor);
```

the DLL is calling correctly but exiting MonitorProc I get an access violation error.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you call `inherited` when the method is abstract in the parent class?

Comment: The procedure in you parrent class is abstract, so no need to call inherited. Which version of Delphi are you uding ;

Comment: You don't need to call inherited, but there is nothing wrong in doing it, and it is good practice, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, `inherited` should be removed but the error persists. I'm using Delphi 10.2. update1. I think the problem could be in the calling convention but I've no idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Missing calling conversion (cdecl) ?

Comment: same error inserting cdecl: `procedure MonitorProc(value1: longint; value2: longint); override; cdecl;`

Comment: the problem is some where in your DLL. (I guess). The code you provided doesn't even compile. 

So please create a new project and verfy you code inside that

Comment: You can't match a C++ class to a Delphi class that way. They simply are not compatible. You'll need to find a different solution.